# Servlet o href no funcionan en JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

En mi menu desplegable utilizo dos enlaces. Funcionaban de los mas bien. En una de las dos paginas jsp que uso, he estado intentado instaurar unos combos en cascada usando JSTL y algo de Jquery. No he logrado esto ultimo, cuando ahora los links no funcionan ni cambiando el tipo de menu. Despliego las jsp dentro de un iFrame en la pagina principal: ahora aparecen en blanco aun las invoque fuera del iFrame.

JSP Principal

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="CaliCombo?menu=Calificaciones&accion=ListarN" target="iMarco">Calificaciones</a></li>
```

Servlet CaliCombo

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String menu = request.getParameter("menu");
    String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
    
    String child = request.getParameter("child"); // ID of child DD to fill options for.
    String val = request.getParameter("val"); // Value of parent DD to find associated child DD options for.
    if (menu.equals("principal")) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("principal.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    
    if (menu.equals("Calificaciones")) {
        switch (accion) {
            case "ListarN":
                List lista = dao.listarN();
                request.setAttribute("nive", lista);
                break;
            case "nivel":
                 ideN=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("val"));
                 List listase = dao.listarS(ideN);
                request.setAttribute("secc", listase);
                break;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError();
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Calificaciones.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    
}
```

La JSP Calificaciones, tiene una tabla y varios combos mas el codigo Jquery.

El misterio es, que dejaron de funcionar de un instante a otro. Es lo que noto dentro de mi poca instruccion en esto.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que te arroja tu error.log que esta dentro de tu servidor? No menciona o envia algun error con respecto a ello?

Comment: Ese es el caso, que no da ningun error.